# Keep getting a global name not defined error

Tags: python, variables, global

```
def defineType(riskCode):
    if riskCode == 1:
        riskType = High
    else:
        if riskCode == 2:
            riskType = Moderate
        else:
            if riskCode == 3:
                riskType = Low
            else:
                if RiskCode == 4:
                    riskType = No
```

This is part of a program I'm working on for a class...

```
# Global Variables
custName = input('Please enter your name: ')
custAge = int(input('Please enter your age: '))
custViolation = int(input('Please enter the number of violations: '))

riskCode = 0
estimatePrice = 0
riskType = none
```

These are my global variable...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 13, in <module>
    riskType = none
NameError: name 'none' is not defined
```

This is the error that I keep getting with different variations depending on what changes I make to try to solve the problem

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!
Alli

Answer (score 16):

It's `None` not `none`. Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 8):

The initial problem I see is that `none` is not a built-in value in Python. `None` is though.

Also, the tower of nested if statements in the first function is unnecessary. Flatten that!

```
def defineType(riskCode):
    if riskCode == 1:
        riskType = High
    elif riskCode == 2:
        riskType = Moderate
    elif riskCode == 3:
        riskType = Low
    elif RiskCode == 4:
        riskType = No
```

It's not an error, but it's much more readable, no? (Easier to type too :)

Also, I take it that `High`, `Moderate`, `Low`, and `No` are defined elsewhere in your code? If you're using them as enumerated constants (i.e. as a set of unique integers whose values do not change), `HIGH`, `MODERATE`, `LOW`, and `NO` would be more idiomatic.

And in fact, if you did that, the whole function could be done away with like so:

```
HIGH = 1
MODERATE = 2
LOW = 3
NO = 4
```

Now you don't need to map them at all; and you can just assign `riskCode` to `riskType`, although that may be a bit redundant now!

```
riskType = riskCode
```

If you want to get strings from risk codes, try the second dictionary [from Artsiom Rudzenka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387839/keep-getting-a-global-name-not-defined-error/6388039#6388039).

Finally... I would suggest putting these codes in their own namespace:

```
class Risk(object):
    HIGH = 1
    MODERATE = 2
    LOW = 3
    NO = 4
```

You can then reference them like so:

```
if riskCode == Risk.HIGH: do_something()
```

Now you are free to use short words like `NO` for other things.

Comment: Also (sorry for the swarm of verbiage!) see [jlargent's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387839/keep-getting-a-global-name-not-defined-error/6388092#6388092) if you're trying to modify riskType as a global within your function.

Comment: I so appreciate your help, after doing what you suggested with changing none to None, and using the elif instead of if...  i get thisTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 79, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 16, in main
    assignRisk()
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 37, in assignRisk
    defineType(riskCode)
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 70, in defineType
    riskType = Moderate
NameError: global name 'Moderate' is not defined

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 79, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 16, in main
    assignRisk()
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 37, in assignRisk
    defineType(riskCode)
  File "C:\Users\Alli\Downloads\HwyRobbery.py", line 70, in defineType
    riskType = Moderate
NameError: global name 'Moderate' is not defined

Comment: And yes...  I'm new...  this is my 1st class, and I got the whole program to work, except the risk code part...  and I'm about to pull my hair out!

Comment: Sorry, as I tried to explain, `Moderate` is a variable name in your code, so you have to define it! Or, if you want it to be a string, you have to put it on quotation marks.

Comment: sooo...  I think I'm in love with you :)  it was the stinkin' quotations...  wow...  its the little things in life... THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 3):

No need to use function to use function for risks mapping you can simply use the following:

```
riskmapping = {1:High, 2:Moderate, 3:Low, 4:No}
```

But in case if High, ...No is not a instances or variables, but just a strings than:

```
riskmapping = {1:'High', 2:'Moderate', 3:'Low', 4:'No'}
```

Usage:

```
highRisk = riskmapping[1]
```

Or

```
if riskmapping[currentRiskCode]:
    #do smth
```

Comment: NameError: name 'High' is not defined

Comment: I'm guessing that Alli OGrady is new to python (sorry if not!) so I think you should show usage.

Comment: Actually i have added my code based on OP code, so i suppose he has definition for this variables, i only give the short version of his code.

Comment: def main():
    assignRisk()
    calculateIns()
    defineType()
    if custAge < 16 or custAge > 105:
        print('Invalid Entry')
    elif custViolation < 0:
        print('Invalid Entry')
    else:
        print(custName, ', as a ', riskType, ' risk driver, your insurance will cost $', estimatePrice, '.00.')


def defineType():
    global riskType
    if riskCode == 1:
        riskType = High
    elif riskCode == 2:
        riskType = Moderate
    elif riskCode == 3:
        riskType = Low
    elif riskCode == 4:
        riskType = No

Answer (score 1):

Apart from none, my contribution to simplicity:

```
riskCodes = {1: 'High', 2: 'Moderate', 3: 'Low', 4: 'No'}

def defineType(riskCode):
    riskType = riskCodes[riskCode]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are modifying global variables in a function other than were it is declared don't
you have to use the global keyword.

```
def defineType(riskCode):
    global riskType

    if riskCode == 1:
        riskType = High
```

Comment: Moving from code that doesn't work at all to code that's very badly designed isn't necessarily a step in the right direction. 95% of the time, the `global` keyword means you're doing something horribly, horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `riskType` inside your function is local to that function and will not affect the value in the global.  You need to tell your function to use the global by putting `global riskType` before code that tries to modify it.

`None` should be capitalized.

I believe you meant to set riskType to a string and therefore those values should be quoted.

Python has an `elif` for `else if`.

The corrected code:

```
# Global Variables
riskCode = 0
estimatePrice = 0
riskType = None

def defineType(riskCode):
    global riskType
    if riskCode == 1:
        riskType = "High"
    elif riskCode == 2:
        riskType = "Moderate"
    elif riskCode == 3:
        riskType = "Low"
    elif RiskCode == 4:
        riskType = "No"
```